# GPG piping help for an S3 encrypted postgresql backup into RDS

Tags: amazon-s3, rds, gpg-agent

I was wondering if there was a trick that I am missing.

I am trying to get an encrypted Postgresql backup dump from S3 -> decrypt it in GPG -> pg_restore into RDS.

However, I am not able to get GPG to work in this piping process and that makes my life much harder.

`aws s3 s3://my-archives/dump.tar.gz - | gpg ??? | pg_restore -h rdsinstance.com -U blabla`

Comment: What gpg command-line options have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, I did ```gpg -a -d -r email@email.com``` but that doesn't work with piping for me

Comment: `-a` creates "ASCII armored" output -> the output is base64 encoded. Are you sure `pg_restore` can handle base64 encoded data?

Comment: No idea.. I'm copy/pasting from a company wiki

Comment: Then the first step should be to read the gpg help for each used parameter and check if it is needed.